# Cursor stops working

Tags: lubuntu

Once I boot up, everything is working great. But after a while, the cursor stops interacting with things. I can move the cursor around the screen, but whenever I try to click, scroll, or right click it simply does not work. I am using a touchpad, and my keyboard still works while all of this is going on. Would love any help

Lubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 0):

1- Check if your touchpad is enabled and configured in the way you want them to be:
**Preferences > LXQt Settings > Mouse and Touchpad**

2- Restart your touchpad driver:
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`

This should unload and reload the touchpad driver, which may fix any issues.